# Rails 4.2 sending records using AMP form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, http-headers, amp-html

I have an amp form in Rails 4.2. According to the AMP validation, everything is in order, but when making the submission of records through the form, the following errors occur:

```
Started POST "/welcome/test?__amp_source_origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-17 09:25:31 -0500
Processing by WelcomeController#test as JSON
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"jQLaggeKmJcAlUnoq1dPqaQ6ALiedxaSaEO7VDCIei/FSEtW3F15TMkhI3cxEqBSggRbWLmZTQUkNXoYUy+5qw==", "name"=>"registerthree", "__amp_source_origin"=>"http://localhost:3000"}
"Los registros han sido enviados correctamente!"
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template welcome/test, application/test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/dd/carpeta_usuario/codigo_de_usuario/AMP/rails-form/app/views"
):
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG90w.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS0XX.png)

The code of the Controller is:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
      def index
      end

      def test
              domain_url = "http://localhost:3000/"
              redirect_url = thankyou_url

              response.headers['Content-type'] =  'application/json'
              response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
              response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*.ampproject.org'
              response.headers['AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin'] = domain_url

              if( redirect_url )
                  response.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin'
              else
                  response.headers['AMP-Redirect-To'] = redirect_url
                  response.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'AMP-Redirect-To, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin'
              end
              puts 'Los registros han sido enviados correctamente!'.to_json
      end

      def thankyou
      end
    end
```

and the view is:

```
    <h1>Formulario AMP</h1>
<p>Ingresa registros</p>
<form target="_top" action-xhr="test" method="post" name="test">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Ingresa un registro!">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

please help me with that. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same problem.